# python opening and appending files

Tags: python, file

need help with this code, line with temperature c is causing bother the syntax error is below

```
tempsFile = open ("temperatures.txt", "r")
cityTable = []
newCityRec = []
for row in tempsFile:
    cityRec = row.split(",")
    city = cityRec[0]
    temperatureC = float(cityRec[1])
    tempF = (temperatureC * 9/5) + 32
    localTime = cityRec[2]
                      
    newCityRec.append(city)
    newCityRec.append(temperatureC)
    newCityRec.append(tempF)
    newCityRec.append(localTime)
                      
    #Append record to table, and clear newCityRec for next record
    cityTable.append(newCityRec)
    newCityRec = []
                      
#All the records are now held in a 2-D list called cityTable
#Sort the list in descending sequence on temperatureC
#Refer to Chapter 7 for how to do this using the lambda function
                      
sortedTable = sorted(cityTable, key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
print ("\nList of cities in descending order of temperature \n")
for n in range (len (sortedTable)):
    print(sortedTable[n][0],sortedTable[n][1], sortedTable[n][2],
    sortedTable[n][3])
tempsFile.close()

            temperatureC = float(cityRec[1])
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ff'
```

thanks for any help. tried this multiple times and just doesnt seem to work

Comment: It would seem that one of your rows has 'ff' in the 2nd column. The error says you are trying to convert 'ff' into a number which will not work.